# How can I merge rasters using GDAL inside Python interpreter or script?

Tags: python, raster, gdal

I am in need of merging rasters within Python script or interpreter, not outside using a command line tool such as gdal_merge.py. Is there a simple way? Or is there a way of executing the command line tool from inside a python script?

Comment: I’m a bit confused, gdal_merge.py is within Python. Why will that not work for you?

Comment: Being it a file, can I call it from inside another .py file? If so, how?

Comment: From what I have seen, gdal_merge.py is a command line tool, I dont know if I can execute that from inside another python script.

Comment: Could you please edit your question with these pertinent details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can call the command line tool from the python script. The library that enables you to do this is [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). The beginning of the page also lists some older libraries.

Here is one short exmaple:

```
# Import module
import subprocess

# Formulate the command as string I used the gdal_translate here
cmd = 'gdal_translate -ot FLOAT32 -of AAIGrid ras1.tif ras2.asc'

# Call
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True')
```